# Two Datacenter location with same BGP AS number but separate Prefixes

Tags: bgp

If APNIC has allocated us a single AS Number e.g 13777 With single ipv4 pool 1.1.1.0/23 can we use 2 prefixes across multiple data centres with same AS No

e.g
Datacentre1 AS no 13777 advertising 1.1.0.0/24
Datacentre2 AS no 13777 advertising 1.1.1.1/24

OR should we get 2 IP pools of /24 each returning the single /23 ipv4 pool to APNIC

Answer (score 0):

This question really belongs in the network engineering community.

The prefix that APNIC allocated to you cannot possibly be 1.1.1.0/23.

1.1.1.0 in binary is:

```
00000001.00000001.00000001.00000000    IP Address
```

The binary mask corresponding to /23 is:

```
11111111.11111111.11111110.00000000    Mask
```

Note that it does not make sense to have a 1 bit in the part of the prefix that is not covered by the mask:

```
                         +-- This bit does not make sense
                         v
00000001.00000001.00000001.00000000    IP Address
11111111.11111111.11111110.00000000    Mask
```

For the sake of argument let's pretend that APNIC assigned you prefix 1.1.2.0/23 which is the following in binary:

```
00000001.00000001.00000010.00000000    IP Address
11111111.11111111.11111110.00000000    Mask
```

You say that you want to use the same AS number 13777 to address two different prefixes, one from each data center.

You can do this yourself by splitting your prefix into two contiguous sub-prefixes, both covered by the covering prefix that you own, as follows:

Sub-prefix 1, advertised by data center 1:

```
1.1.2.0/24

00000001.00000001.00000010.00000000    IP Address
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000    Mask
```

Sub-prefix 2, advertised by data center 12:

```
1.1.3.0/24

00000001.00000001.00000011.00000000    IP Address
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000    Mask
```

Note that you are completely within your rights to advertise sub-prefixes of the prefix that APNIC assigned to you. This is normal and happens in real life.

There is no need for you to return the /23 prefixes to APNIC and to ask for /24 prefixes instead.